# Clock applet stops after login

Tags: 10.04, gnome, panel, clock

I realized a second strange thing after upgrading from 8.04 LTS to 10.04. My (GNOME) panel contains the clock applet. This applet shows current date and time. The time is not upgraded after I start a GNOME session. When I remove the applet and insert it again, it works fine. But at some point it stops again. Has anyone seen this? Is there a workaround? Several other people seem to have the same problem, but as far as I saw it they had no solution.

Comment: Does the clock stop after you do something in particular? I just read where someone noticed it stop after watching a Youtube video.

Comment: Well, actually this happens at my girlfriends account. as far as I can see she visits webpages (plain text, no javascript or flash). But until now we didn't we figure out when it happens. There is only an approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [bug report on this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/575410) [one commenter](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/575410/comments/17) says that a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/439448/comments/205) for [another bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/439448) fixed the clock freezing problem for him. The workaround delays the startup of gnome-panel for three seconds. (Strange, eh?)

Here is the workaround:

1. Create a script called delayed-gnome-panel.sh in your home directory and mark it as executable.
2. Edit the script to look like this:

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   sleep 3 && gnome-panel &
   exit
   ```
3. Then edit /usr/share/applications/gnome-panel.desktop so that `exec=bash /home/<user>/delayed-gnome-panel.sh`.

Comment: Today the panel completely disappeared. I have no clue why. So I moved the `.gconf`-folder and restarted GNOME. Right now it seems that also my clock problem disappeared. Thatswhy I mark my question as solved.

Comment: Did my answer actually answer the question, or did you find another way? If my answer wasn't the solution, you should add your own answer and mark it as the solution.