# How can I find out what is causing my gnome-panel to freeze?

Tags: gnome, panel, debug

About once a day my gnome-panel freezes.

How can I produce some sort of debug information to:

- Figure out what is causing the freeze or
- File a bug or see if its an existing bug

When gdb is attached to gnome-panel and the bug occurs I cannot get a stack trace out of gdb.

```
Reading symbols from /lib/libbz2.so.1.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libbz2.so.1.0
0x00007f7cefe10f48 in poll () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) c
Continuing.

^C
^C
```

The "^C" is to show that once the bug occurs gdb stops responding to Ctrl+c and kill -INT.

Comment: You might want to check with this: http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/678/clock-applet-stops-after-login

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for deletion :)

Comment: Yes, I never learned how to find out what was wrong. And now gnome-panel is not supported by Ubuntu so this question is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: I stopped using gnome-panel altogether soon after so no, I don't have that issue any more. I think I remember it still happened even with only the clock applet running. I never got a good stack trace for the panel out of GDB either.

Answer (score 4):

The comments on [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/355915) on the same issue first point the reporter to a wiki page entitled [Debugging a Program Crash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash) and then to a page describing [how to get a backtrace](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Backtrace). Perhaps those will help you get the debugging info you need.

I answered a [question about a similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678/clock-applet-stops-after-login) with a workaround that may help you. It goes like this:

1. Create a script called delayed-gnome-panel.sh in your home directory and mark it as executable.
2. Edit the script to look like this:

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   sleep 3 && gnome-panel &
   exit
   ```
3. Then edit /usr/share/applications/gnome-panel.desktop so that `exec=bash /home/<user>/delayed-gnome-panel.sh`.

Comment: That bug report seems to be related. I would prefer to know what the cause of the problem is and get it fixed permanently rather than adding MORE delay hacks to my desktop startup.

Comment: Did the debugging info in the report not help any?

Comment: Not really, that is the first article that pops up about debugging. I cant get a stack trace out of gdb for this bug in gnome-panel. Ill put some more detail in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Attach to the panel **after** it's frozzen.

```
$ gdb --pid=`pidof gnome-panel`
(gdb) bt full
```

Also make sure you have the necessary debugging symbols installed. At least libglib2.0-0-dbg and libgtk2.0-0-dbg.

Answer (score 2):

To debug the gnome-panel from the beginning you can try:

```
$ gnome-session-remove gnome-panel
$ gdb gnome-panel
...
(gdb) run
```

You would need the debugging symbols in order to get something readable (ie gnome-panel-dbg).