# Gnome-Panel freezes occasionally

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel, freeze

Hey folks,
I have a problem with my Gnome-Panel. Occasionally my gnome-panel freezes, meaning that all icons (network status, sound, etc.) freeze along with the time displayed. When I kill the process, the panel restarts automatically and works just fine. Is there a way to prevent the panel from freezing?

Thx in advance for any help, suggestion link etc!

Cherio Woltan

PS A new phenomenon occurred. After booting Ubuntu the panel didn't load at all, however I was able to access the menu and other icons by hovering over their usual positions. After a reboot the panel worked just fine...

Comment: What applets do you use?

Comment: As far as I know only: Weather Report 2.30.0, Indicator Applet Session 0.4.6, Clock 2.30.2, NetworkManager Applet 0.8.1

Comment: So you did not add any applets of your own volition, you mean?

Comment: Apart from the Weather Applet,..., No. Do you think, that this applet freezes my Gnome-Panel? I'll uninstall it and see if the problems continue.

Comment: I uninstalled all applets I added myself but the panel still freezes. Sometimes the menues *Application*, *Places* and *System* do not display, but it still works if I hover with the mouse over the area. Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot find your problem in these bug reports about freezing gnome-panels:

- At [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel?field.searchtext=freeze&orderby=-importance&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=)
- At [GNOME's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=product%3A%22gnome-panel%22+freeze)

then have a look at [How can I find out what is causing my gnome-panel to freeze?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787/how-can-i-find-out-what-is-causing-my-gnome-panel-to-freeze) and open a new bug report (see [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)).