FFMPEG AMF Hardware Acceleration on AMD Ryzen™ 7 7700 Server in Ubuntu 22.04
I was trying to make ffmpeg available with AMF and have access to the AMF hardware acceleration (in ffmpeg -hwaccels) but failed.
At first, the kernel that the server as Ubuntu 22.04 came with was 5.15 and after contacting support I was explained that I need to upgrade the kernel to have access to /dev/dri.
So I upgraded to 6.8 and then I had access to /dev/dri and was able to use ffmpeg 7.1 with vaapi working.
In AMD, they have their own hardware acceleration named AMF, that allows much better speed and quality of transcoding.
I installed the AMD GPU drivers like it's explained here: https://www.amd.com/en/support/download/linux-drivers.html
I installed AMF as well, and compiled my own ffmpeg build with --enable-amf flag.
Still in ffmpeg -hwaccels I get access to vaapi and drm only.
Can you share if you know any solution to this enigma?
These are the instructions with which I installed the drivers, AMF and ffmpeg with:
Install AMD GPU Pro Drivers:
wget https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install…60203-1_all.deb
sudo apt install ./amdgpu-install_6.2.60203-1_all.deb

amdgpu-install --usecase=amf,multimedia -y
sudo amdgpu-install -y --usecase=amf,graphics --accept-eula --opencl=rocr,legacy --vulkan=amdvlk,pro



CompilationGuide/Ubuntu – FFmpeg
Compiling ffmpeg:

sudo apt-get update -qq && sudo apt-get -y install \
autoconf \
automake \
build-essential \
cmake \
git-core \
libass-dev \
libfreetype6-dev \
libgnutls28-dev \
libmp3lame-dev \
libtool \
libvorbis-dev \
meson \
ninja-build \
pkg-config \
texinfo \
wget \
yasm \
zlib1g-dev

sudo apt install libunistring-dev libaom-dev libdav1d-dev -y

mkdir -p ~/ffmpeg_sources ~/bin

// Install prerequisites
apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
build-essential \
pkg-config \
yasm \
nasm \
libtool \
automake \
cmake \
libx264-dev \
libx265-dev \
libvpx-dev \
libfdk-aac-dev \
libopus-dev \
libaom-dev \
libdrm-dev \
libva-dev \
vainfo
    
    
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
wget https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-7.1.tar.bz2 && \
tar -xjf ffmpeg-7.1.tar.bz2 && \
mkdir ffmpeg_build && \
cd ffmpeg_build && \
mkdir include && \
cd include && \


// Install AMF
git clone https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF.git && \
mv ~/ffmpeg_build/include/AMF/amf ~/ffmpeg_build/include/ && \
rm -rf AMF && \

// From here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1440…-ubuntu-20-04-5
// Correct install:
cd ~/
git clone https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF.git
mkdir /usr/local/include/AMF
cd /usr/local/include/AMF
ln -sf ~/AMF/amf/public/include/core
ln -sf ~/AMF/amf/public/include/components

// Install libvmaf
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
wget https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf/archive/v3.0.0.tar.gz && \
tar xvf v3.0.0.tar.gz && \
mkdir -p vmaf-3.0.0/libvmaf/build && \

cd vmaf-3.0.0/libvmaf && \
meson setup build --buildtype=release --default-library=static --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" && \
ninja -C build && \
ninja -C build install

cd ~/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-7.1
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
--prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
--pkg-config-flags="--static" \
--extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
--extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
--extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
--ld="g++" \
--bindir="$HOME/bin" \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-gnutls \
--enable-libaom \
--enable-libass \
--enable-libfdk-aac \
--enable-libfreetype \
--enable-libmp3lame \
--enable-libopus \
--enable-libdav1d \
--enable-libvorbis \
--enable-libvpx \
--enable-libx264 \
--enable-libx265 \
--enable-libdrm \
--enable-vaapi \
--enable-libvmaf \
--enable-amf \
--enable-nonfree && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
make -j$(nproc) install && \
hash -r


./ffmpeg -buildconf



Test VMAF to compare quality:
./ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i reference.mp4 -lavfi libvmaf -f null -
// example output: [Parsed_libvmaf_0 @ 0x74a0f8004940] VMAF score: 98.930249ate=N/A speed=9.06x


I installed jellyfin, amdgpu and jellyfin's ffmpeg includes amf.
/usr/lib/jellyfin-ffmpeg/ffmpeg
